# NotWritableError conda installing new module

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, conda, brackets

I am getting this error in windows platform, after creating virtual environment whenever I am trying to run `conda` command to install any package this error occurs.

```
(py36) C:\Users\ND_Londhe>conda install -c anaconda spyder
Solving environment: failed
NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: C:\C:\Users\ND_Londhe\Anaconda2\pkgs\urls.txt
```

All solutions out there are for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you must use your root permission to install the package ,so Don't use the user to install. try it and it's fine!